# Select distinct record from union query

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, distinct

I have multiple tables with OS_Data from different application databases and scan engines, which I've given the data a priority based on the clarity of the data.  I want to get a list of unique hostnames with the lowest priority and the relevant OS of that priority

Table1

| Hostname | Operating_System | OS_Priority |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ServerA | Windows Server 2016 | 1 |
| ServerB | Windows | 2 |
| ServerC | Windows Server 2016 | 1 |
| ServerE | Windows Server 2016 | 1 |

Table2

| Hostname | Operating_System | OS_Priority |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ServerA | Windows | 2 |
| ServerB | Windows Server 2012 R2 | 1 |
| ServerC | Windows Server 2016 1809 | 1 |
| ServerD | Unknown | 3 |
| ServerE | Unknown | 3 |

Table3

| Hostname | Operating_System | OS_Priority |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ServerA | Windows Server 2016 1809 | 1 |
| ServerC | Windows | 2 |
| ServerE | Windows Server 2016 1809 | 1 |

Expected Result

| Hostname | Operating_System |
| --- | --- |
| ServerA | Windows Server 2016 |
| ServerB | Windows Server 2012 R2 |
| ServerC | Windows Server 2016 1809 |
| ServerD | Unknown |
| ServerE | Windows Server 2016 1809 |

I just need the top distinct Hostname along with it's Operating_System.  If there is a tie, then it doesn't matter which result I get, I just need 1 record

Potentially I could be adding five or six tables together but just using three for the example.

This will give me a list of distinct records

```sql
SELECT Hostname, Operating_System, OS_Priority FROM [Table1] 
UNION
SELECT Hostname, Operating_System, OS_Priority FROM[Table2]
UNION
SELECT Hostname, Operating_System, OS_Priority FROM[Table3]
WHERE Hostname is not null
ORDER BY Hostname, OS_Priority
```

I've tried using MIN(OS_Priority) and GROUP BY Hostname but I can't get results to include Operating_System.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance

Comment: So why is ServerA the priority1 from table1 and not table3?

Comment: Hi Stu, there's no priority on the table as each data source could report back a less detailed OS compared to others or maybe not have a record for that hostname. 

The data sources come from different applications that could have an agent on the machine or could be form scans performed by security software on the network.  I created a central repository for all the OS's and created a weighting for the description using some basic logic for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a job for ROW_NUMBER.

Wrap your union a subquery and add a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HostName ORDER BY OS_priority)`, and finally only get the top row:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HostName ORDER BY OS_priority) AS sort
  FROM (
    SELECT Hostname, Operating_System, OS_Priority
    FROM [Table1] 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Hostname, Operating_System, OS_Priority
    FROM [Table2]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Hostname, Operating_System, OS_Priority
    FROM [Table3]
    WHERE Hostname IS NOT NULL
  ) x
) x
WHERE x.sort = 1
```

Comment: You're a star, thanks a million!!